# Existing Table Rows Being Overwritten (RDS, MySQL)

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm experiencing a strange issue where my existing table rows (RDS MySQL) are being overwritten. Running a SPA (Vuetify). When a user POSTs data, it overwrites an existing table row, rather than creating a new row.

The weird thing is it happens only sometimes, seemingly at random. Sometimes it will function correctly, other times it overwrites existing data. I cannot link anything in the logs to these events, nor connect it to a specific error.

We have two DATETIME fields that sometimes give incorrect timestamps, other times the timestamp comes in blank 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

The issue seems to have come out of nowhere. Has anyone experienced anything like this?

CREATE TABLE `media` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `content_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` enum('image','video','pdf','link') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=132 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

Comment: Yes. Many users have experienced this. It was an error in their code. Show us that code (the code that gets executed when POST happens).

Comment: here's a snippet of the post...
      }
      const axiosResponse = await api.post(`content/${media.content_id}/media/${media.id}`, payload)
      media = axiosResponse.data.media
      App.dispatch('message', { text: 'The media has been updated!' })
    }
  }

  static async beforeDelete (media) {
    // {{ api }}/content/1/media/1
    if (media.id && media.created_at) {
      api.delete(`content/${media.content_id}/media/${media.id}`)